# "Find Call Hierarchy" not working in Xcode (big project with cocoapods)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'm trying to maintain a huge iOS project which has more than a hundred of classes and cocoapods as dependence manager.

When I try to do a "Find Call Hierarchy" on a function which has some uses, it doesn't show the uses of the function. Instead of showing anything, it plays a "beep" sound. No errors displayed.

Maybe it's necessary to configure something in Xcode? maybe it's a bug on Xcode last version?

Answer (score 2):

These features in Xcode are in general very very buggy so it is not weird at all for them not to work.

I would suggest not to rely on Xcode and have a second window with for instance Appcode or VSCode on the project and do your searches in that.

Comment: I come from Eclipse and Android Studio and Call Hierarchy is a must in a big project with thousands of lines of code in hundreds of classes

Comment: Yeah, well this isn't Java land so there is no 10+ years of history and expectation of these tools working (for better and worse). You could also run Appcode at the same time which seems to be a lot better for this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Clean the project and terminate Xcode, and delete all cache files in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.

And open the project on Xcode and keep for a while. Perhaps best to take a coffee break :)

It should work after all.

Answer (score 0):

After "Clean Build Folder" Xcode needs to re-index the project. Give Xcode some time to finish the indexing, after that "Find call hierarchy" should work again.
Builds/Tests/etc may interrupt the indexing, so prepare for a coffee break.